# Как сделать автоматический установщик нескольких программ?

Tags: windows, установка, windowsinstaller

Как сделать setup.exe который устанавливает определенные программы? Сделать все автоматический чтобы не указывать путь, не ставить галочки и.т.д. И сделать чтобы этот exe все делал и на других ПК. Мне надо чтобы он автоматический установил java и ncalayer. ОС скорее Windows

Comment: Уточните хотя бы целевые ОС! А лучше и программы перечислите (может быть все уже изобретено до вас) Да и вообще, опишите первоисточник проблемы - может быть у нее куда более простое решение, типа разворачивания образов ОС со всем установленным.

Comment: мне надо чтобы он автоматический установил java и ncalayer. ОС скорее Windows

Comment: Добавляйте эти и другие уточнения в сам вопрос (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, большинство инсталляторов программ поддерживают управление установкой - из командной строки и/или настроечным файлом (.INI, .SIF и т.п.). Читайте документацию на конкретную программу установки (или попробуйте нечто вроде SETUP /?).

В частности, для **Java** есть вполне вменяемое описание [Как выполнить фоновую установку Java (установку без участия пользователя)?](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/silent_install.xml)

По тихой установке **NCALayer** настоятельно рекомендую проконсультироваться с техподдержкой разработчика [НУЦ РК](http://www.pki.gov.kz/index.php/ru/tekhnicheskaya-podderzhka).

Во-вторых, при установке .MSI-пакетов также возможно управление процессом установки ключами запуска MSIEXEC.EXE. См. [Command-Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Standard Installer Command-Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx) и т.п.

Comment: не совсем понял. в командной сроке я только знаю чтобы он запускался. как сделать чтобы юзер ничего не нажимал (такие как далее, ок и.т.д). Мне надо установить две программы автоматический java и ncalayer

Comment: А зачем НУЦ РК ? что спросить?

Comment: _зачем НУЦ РК ?_ А затем, что это, как я уже сказал, РАЗРАБОТЧИК программы NCALayer. Который лучше других знает, можно ли, и если да, то как именно.